# Is ProcedureKit Swift 3 ready?

Tags: swift3, nsoperation

Doesn't seem to be: when I open the workspace after a pod install, I'm asked to do a Swift 3 conversion. Is there a timeline?

Comment: Thorpe asks that questions be directed to him on stackoverflow. howerver I'm not sure how to target him at @daniel.thorpe as indicated.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for stack overflow. Please post questions/issues on the [project's issues page](https://github.com/ProcedureKit/ProcedureKit/issues).

Answer (score 1):

*ProcedureKit* is Swift 3 ready, although it's still in beta at the moment - some breaking changes might occur, and it's not 100% feature compatible with *Operations v3.4*.

If you are integrating via CocoaPods, you will need to point to the `development` branch, e.g.

```
pod 'ProcedureKit/Network', :git => 'https://github.com/ProcedureKit/ProcedureKit.git', :branch => 'development'
```

Additionally, depending on your settings (maybe put a .swift-version) in your project - the way that CocoaPods creates the intermediate framework, might default to Swift 2.3. You can get round this by adding:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Hope that helps.